# Mutual perpendicular line between two axes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, kinematics

I'm going through a robotics textbook Introduction to Robotics Mechanics and Control 3rd edition by John J. Craig and am currently on a section describing the relationships between links of some robotic manipulator.

The text contains a figure shown below that has two axes and a link connecting them. There are two numbers that relates the location of the two axes in space - the distance between them written as a, and the link twist alpha.

[image]

The text claims "For any two axes in 3-space, there exists a well defined measure of distance between them (a as written above). This distance is measured along a line that is mutually perpendicular to both axes. The mutual perpendicular always exists; it is unique except when both axes are parallel."

But I'm pretty sure a mutual perpendicular won't always exist. Won't a mutual perpendicular **only** exist if the two axes are parallel in the plane that cuts through both of them? If the two axes will intersect at some point, there shouldn't be a line that is perpendicular to both axes at any point. Is my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is incorrect.  The two axes are just skew lines that have a well-defined minimum distance line segment between them, and this line segment is perpendicular to both of the skew lines.

Comment: Curves don't even have to be linear to have mutually orthogonal points so arguing that they're restricted to some plane is unreasonable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_trajectory

Comment: In some cases the mutually perpendicular line must be curved then, correct? I understand that a curve can achieve this but it seemed that the text is implying a straight line. If that's not the case then I understand. I don't see how a straight line could be mutually perpendicular to the two lines y1=x, y2=2x. @HosamHAJEER

Comment: @MAP3 The lines we're talking about are lines in $3D$ space, and do not lie in the same plane.  Except, if the two lines are parallel.  You are right that $y_1 = x $ and $y_2 = 2 x$  have no line perpendicular to both, but this case is excluded here.

Comment: @HosamHAJEER Ok I think I understand better now and see how limiting my lines to R2 causes issues. Intuitively I see how this mutually perpendicular line is also the shortest distance between the two lines. But this excludes the case where alpha equals zero. In that scenario is it correct to say the mutually perpendicular line doesn't exist (because it's technically of length 0 using the shortest distance reasoning)?

Comment: If alpha is zero, then the two lines are parallel, and the shortest distance between is well defined.  However, the only difference here, is the line segment extending from one axes to the other with the minimum distance is not well-defined, because you extend the shortest distance vector from axis 1 to axis 2 all along the length of axis 1.

Comment: @HosamHAJEER you're right, I didn't ask my question correctly, I apologize. So this orthogonal line exists in every case except when the two lines lie in the same plane and are not parallel, correct? In this case the lines intersect and there is no minimum distance other than 0? This sort of simplifies the space to R2 but this can happen with 3D lines. Thanks for sticking with me on this.

Comment: That's correct.  You got it now.

Comment: Actually, if two lines intersect, they lie in a single plane and the line that is orthogonal to that plane and passes through the point of intersection is perpendicular to both lines. So even that case is not an exception; what is different there is that since both lines intersect the mutually perpendicular line at the same point, the distance $a$ is zero. (Note that although the figure shows only a line *segment* between the two axes, a *line* in mathematics is usually considered to extend indefinitely in both directions.)

Comment: If you represent the direction of these two lines with vectors $z_{i-1}$ and $z_i$ for non-parallel lines then perpendicular direction is represented by the vector product  $z_{i-1} \times z_i$

Comment: @DavidK I see that now, thank you for the response. I wonder what kind of implications that has for robotic systems when a is zero. So far the book hasn't covered that case. These parameters will eventually come together to perform forward/inverse kinematics so I assume the math can account for that possibility in some way, but I'm not sure how.